# "Payscale-like" feature for Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Do you think a wage-comparison engine can be an interesting feature for the **Career** section of **Stack Exchange.**

**Payscale** is a very useful website which I guess most of us already known. I've been looking with a strong enthusiasm to the Career section of Stack Exchange.

The part where this site is really strong are two:

- Community
- Development of the solution

The point where Payscale is really lacking are about the tags (i.e. the distinguish between ".net developer" and "software developer" and "software engineer" are really liable and volatile, they should be tag, attributes or axis rather than completely separated kind of work)

Another issue with Payscale is that you should always specify for first the country while the salary data should be project-able on every axis (I can choose to go to the country which offers me the best salary).

Comment: What would this feature do exactly?

Comment: Allow SE member to insert their salary (gross, bonus, profit sharing) city where they work, sex. Years in Field/Career (can be calculated from the already inserted data) and get exactly the same kind of information provided by Payscale in this report: http://www.payscale.com/research/DE/Job=SAP_Consultant/Salary. The biggest difference would be about the handling of the different name for similar work as explained in the question.

Comment: Do you mean they should enter this information in the careers profile, or on Stack Overflow?`

Comment: @I think the best solution would be to enter these information in their career profile